# Is it possible to declare a string type without fixed length for filtering on fixed length characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way in sql where I can declare a string type without a fixed length for filtering on a nvarchar field with a fixed length?

For example this is what I have to do now -

```
declare @input nvarchar(255)
set @input = 'test'
select * from table
where field = @input
```

This is something along the line of what I want to be able to do -

```
declare @input string
set @input = 'test'
select * from table
where field = @input
```

Answer (score 3):

Just declare your variables as nvarchar(4000) or nvarchar(max).

The lengths of the strings do not need to match for the comparison to work, for variable length strings.

This is not true of fixed length strings, but that is another matter entirely.